# Delete the last row of excel file using SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an SSIS package that creates and populates an excel sheet, it creates the sheet from a template file.

I want to check the Excel file by "startdate",if a new product to be added, must this new product be deleted. and then send a warning e-mail

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is "Start Date" held on a database somewhere? If so you could read this value using an "Execute SQL task" or "Lookup" and store the value as a variable.

A "Conditional split" could then compare the date with that coming from the flat file. If the Start Date in the file is later than your stored value then output this data to a flat file/alternate database.

In a separate data flow task check for records in the flat file/alternate database.
If there are records then send an email with the flat file data as an attachment.